# Several stars in line

Tags: star

I can see several stars in the sky they can make a line come from the West south and going to East north direction at the time between 6.50 to 7.00 pm Indian time on date 13.1.20. What might these three stars be?

Comment: You can use software such as [Stellarium](https://stellarium-web.org/) to determine what those stars were. Simply input your date and time of observation, along with your location, and you can compare what you see in the app to what you see in the sky. You can also set the amount of light pollution so that the sky in the app most closely resembles the real sky. There also are mobile apps such as SkyChart that offer similar functionalities.

Comment: Were the "stars" moving? If so, it could be the Starlink satellites.

Comment: @antispinwards considering the use of "coming from" and "going to", it seems likely.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica since it is *three* satellites and not dozens, it could also be the [A-train constellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-train_(satellite_constellation)) so I think the close-vote is premature.

Comment: @uhoh The A-train constellation is sun synchronous and passes around 1:30 am/pm, so the time frame doesn't fit.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by moving as we commonly describe stars as non moving objects, at least in a time interval of 10 min and if not  taking photographs or so.

Answer (score 1):

It might be orion as in this season it is pretty clear in India. Orion have three stars in a somewhat straight line.

From in-the-sky.org's [planetarium](https://in-the-sky.org/skymap.php) at 19:00 Indian time near the center of the subcontinent, [Orion's Belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion%27s_Belt) is high in the sky and extends from the East-Southeast vertically towards the zenith.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But hardly one would describe the Orion's belt as moving. It might be, I think the OP should clarify the Q