# Saw 8 stars moving in same direction one by one

Tags: star, observational-astronomy, astrophysics

I saw 8 stars moving in the same direction one by one and then at the same point they faded or you can say disappear. The speed was not too fast but not too slow either. I am more curious because there were 8 of them and one by one they came from the same direction, move in the same direction and disappear at the same place. What could it be satellites or were the actually stars?

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. But in the video, it's pretty obvious they are not stars. I sometimes watch the night sky. So I have seen a few moving stars. Those were exactly like stars. On the same height as stars. That's why I am confused.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same height as stars" ?

Comment: the link you shared. If you see that, those satellites, you can actually tell that they are not stars plus they weren't that high on the sky. But when you look at stars you can just tell that they are pretty far. That's what I am trying to say.

Comment: Satellites aren't always low on the horizon. If the video had been take at a different lattitude in fact, the satellites could have seemed to be higher in the sky.

Comment: What specifically makes you think that what you saw was not satellites?

Comment: No, I am not saying that those aren't satellites. Besides the way they move in the same direction makes me doubt that they can be satellites. But thanks for your answer. That was a pretty amazing site actually. Besides night sky are always beautiful. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Several stars in line](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/34706/several-stars-in-line)

Comment: Thank you so much Dave.